# Stop NebulaGraph From Using Cassandra Ports

Tags: docker, docker-container, nebula-graph, tcp-port, tcpportsharing

## Problem

Please let me know how I can improve this question in the comments below!

How do I stop [`NebulaGraph Docker Desktop Extension`](https://www.docker.com/blog/distributed-cloud-native-graph-database-nebulagraph-docker-extension/) from using the `TCP-Port: 7001`?

I know how to manually stop [NebulaGraph](https://hub.docker.com/extensions/weygu/nebulagraph-dd-ext) by toggling on the extension to show its containers (I'm not that new to Docker anymore ).
My goal is to have the [Graph-Database](https://www.g2.com/categories/graph-databases) and [Cassandra [Docker]](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra) startup automatically.

[image: Show Docker Extensions system containers]

I expected to see a [NebulaGraph Doc](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.4.1/) that would tell me how to stop the automatic startup. 
Or, I'd find setting-options toggle on the NebulaGraph-Extension or Docker-Extensions. 
But I found no such information nor way to stop just the NebulaGraph-Extension.

[image: Docker containers with port 7001]

I know one of the following would work here:

1. Change the TCP-Port of the NebulaGraph-Extension
2. Allow TCP-Port sharing with NebulaGraph-Extension and Cassandra-Docker-container
3. Stop just the singular `studio-1` container or all on Docker-startup

But I just can't seem to find in when I look through their documentation.

[image: weygu_nebulagraph-dd-ext-desktop-extension]

If there's something wrong about how I'm asking, please let me know in the comments so I can fix them!

Comment: In case you missed it: we released a new version of the NebulaGraph docker extension, and it's now with new port other than 7001 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: A new version of NebulaGraph docker ext was released, now the studio exposed ports are 17001 & 17002 :).

Author of NebulaGraph docker extension here,

Sorry for just knowing that 7001 is "well-known" for Cassandra now, could you help with an issue on https://github.com/nebula-contrib/nebulagraph-docker-ext/issues/new?

I could change its exposed port from 7001 to 17001 in the next extension release.

Thanks!

BR//Wey

Answer (score 0):

There is no way at time of asking this question. 
The only way to handle this is to write your own custom code to perform such a request.

Comment: We are hearing from you, and will try to revisit all exposed ports and avoid such conflicts in the next release, could you please kindly help report an issue? Thanks!